# When using iTextSharp to combine PDF files, an issue occurred where some pages were missing

Tags: powershell, itext

I am a novice developer, Toru. I usually work with C# for development.

I was tasked with creating a tool to combine PDFs. Due to operational requirements, I needed to script it in PowerShell. I ended up using the ItextSharp.dll to perform PDF merging within PowerShell.

While I was able to successfully merge the PDFs, I encountered an issue during testing. The problem was that there were blank pages inserted between the merged PDFs. For example, let's say I merged a 10-page [AAA.pdf] with a 10-page [BBB.pdf]. The issue caused the merged PDF of [AAA.pdf] to have blank pages inserted between its 1st and 2nd pages, adding about 2-3 pages of blank space. This resulted in missing pages as well.

I tried to reproduce this issue by testing in the following ways, but I couldn't replicate it:

・Testing with the same PDF files.

・Testing with the same PDF files, ensuring that the size after merging was larger than when the issue occurred.

Apart from that specific scenario, I haven't encountered the issue again, and I don't know how to reproduce it.

Overview of the process:

1:Obtain an array of paths for merging files that are filled in Excel.

2：Enter the conditional branch to perform PDF merging if the variable [GrupeNo] changes its value on the Excel sheet.

3：If the output PDF file doesn't exist, create the file.

4：Check if values are present in the array; if they are, enter the conditional branch to perform PDF merging.

5：Add references to the DLLs.

6：If specific filenames exist within a designated folder, append them to the beginning of the output PDF file.

7：Acquire objects of the output PDF file.

8：Acquire objects of the PDFs to be merged, and append them to the output PDF file.

9：Release objects of the PDFs to be merged.

10：Repeat steps 8 and 9.

Additionally, the following code is provided in PowerShell.

```
            #The 'if' statement for performing PDF merging
            if($GrupeNo -ne [int]$worksheet.Cells.Item($r, 5).Text)
            {
                #The variable [PdfName] holds the full path of the PDF to be created
                $PdfName = ($UserFullPath + "\"+ $StrFileName + [string]$GrupeNo + ".pdf")

                #If the output destination PDF does not exist, create a new output destination PDF file
                if((Test-Path $PdfName) -eq $false){
                    
                    New-Item -path $UserFullPath -Name ($StrFileName + [string]$GrupeNo +".pdf")  -ItemType "File"
                    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 3000
                }



                #I am checking whether there is a path for the PDF files to be merged

                if ($ActivePdfFiles.Length -ne 0) 
                {
                    
                    Set-ItemProperty -path $PdfName -name IsReadOnly -value $false
                    $FSO = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($PdfName , [System.IO.FileMode]::OpenOrCreate)
                    $BeforPassivePdfFile = New-Object iTextSharp.text.Document 
                    $PassivePdfFile = New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfSmartCopy($BeforPassivePdfFile,$FSO)
                    $BeforPassivePdfFile.Open()
                    

                    $refFirstPdfPath = Join-Path $Location "cover page" 
                    $FirstPdfPath = Join-Path $refFirstPdfPath  ($StrFileName + [string]$GrupeNo +".pdf")
                    
                    #Processing of the cover page PDF file
                    if(($PDFNum -eq 0) -and ((test-path $FirstPdfPath) -eq $true))
                    {

                        $ActivePdfFile=New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader($FirstPdfPath) 
                        $PassivePdfFile.AddDocument($ActivePdfFile);
                        $ActivePdfFile.Close(); 
                        $PDFNum = 1
                    }
                
                    #The iterative loop performing the PDF merging
                    for ($i = $NumCheck ; $i -lt $ActivePdfFiles.Count; $i++) 
                    {
                        if((test-path $ActivePdfFiles[$i]) -eq $false)
                        {
                            continue
                        }
                        
                        $ActivePdfFile=New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader($ActivePdfFiles[$i])
                        $PassivePdfFile.AddDocument($ActivePdfFile);

                        $ActivePdfFile.Close();                    
                    }
                    $NumCheck = $ActivePdfFiles.Length
                }

               #Releasing the objects
               if ($ActivePdfFile -ne $null) 
               {
                   $ActivePdfFile.dispose()
               }

               if ($PassivePdfFile -ne $null) 
               {
                   $PassivePdfFile.Dispose();
               }
               if ($FSO -ne $null) 
               {
                   $fso.Dispose();
               }
               if ($PhotoPdfFile -ne $null) 
               {
                   $PhotoPdfFile.Dispose();
               }
               
               $GrupeNoCheck = $GrupeNo
            }
```

Used DLLs:

・itextsharp.dll (version 5.5.13.3)

・BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll

Anticipated PDFs for merging:

・Number of files: 1 to 20

・File size: 400KB to 15MB per file

Output PDF file:

・File size: Less than 10MB → Mandatory

In this case, what could be the potential cause of the issue?

I'm sorry, but I would greatly appreciate your guidance.

Comment: Consider calling `$PassivePdfFile.FreeReader($ActivePdfFile)` before `$ActivePdfFile.Close()`. You might currently close the `PdfReader` before your `PdfSmartCopy` has retrieved all the data from it that is needed.

Comment: You're very welcome! I've added that and I'm running it now.